# How to hide part of css when input is empty?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to hide the search result when the search is back to empty. Is there a way to do that?

Everything is working fine. I just don't like to see the search result of the last letter. Example if you type A and you empty the input box. The result will stay there.

Thanks to the person that know the answer.

`<div id="result"></div>` should be the one to be blocked.

My CSS code for the search:

```
.content{
    width:275px;

}
#searchid
{
    width:275px;
    border:solid 1px #000;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:14px;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
#result
{
    position: absolute;
    width:275px;
    padding:10px;
    display:none;

    border-top:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px #CCC solid;
    background-color: white;
}
.show
{
    padding:10px;
    border-bottom:1px #999 dashed;
    font-size:15px;
    height:50px;
}
.show:hover
{
    background:lightgrey;
    color:#FFF;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

My HTML Code for the search input box:

```
<div class="content">
                        <input type="text" class="search" id="searchid" placeholder="Search"/>
                        <div id="result"></div>
                    </div>
```

My Search Display are like that:

```
<div class="show" align="left">
                           <span class="name"><a href="/sheridan/page/?p=' .  $rowsTitle['id'] . '">' . $rowsTitle['title'] . '</a> ' . $label . "<br>".
                      </div>
```

JQuery that I use to get the search information:

```
$(function(){
        $(".search").keyup(function()
        {
            var searchid = $(this).val();
            var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;
            if(searchid!='')
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/sheridan/script/search.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html)
                    {
                        $("#result").html(html).show();
                    }

                });
            }return false;
        });

        jQuery("#result").live("click",function(e){
            var $clicked = $(e.target);
            var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
            var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
            $('#searchid').val(decoded);
        });
        jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) {
            var $clicked = $(e.target);
            if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
                jQuery("#result").fadeOut();
            }
        });
        $('#searchid').click(function(){
            jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
        });
    });
```

I forgot to add the JQuery function that I use to get the information out of the database.

Comment: Write code on search textbox keyup event.. and find if textbox blank remove all result.

Comment: I tried that:
    $(".content").on({
        keydown: function(){
            $("#result").addClass("active");
        },
        blur: function () {
            $("#result").removeClass('active');
        },
        keyup: function () {
            if ( $(this).val() == "" ) {
                $("#result").removeClass('active');
            }
        }
    });

And it was not working...

Comment: instead of `$("#result").removeClass('active');` try `$("#result").html("");`

Comment: `#result:empty { display:none; }`? http://jsfiddle.net/gg66ubbL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't cleared the result div as you are filling it with data when there is a letter.

```
$(".search").on("keyup", function(){
    if($(this).val()==""){
        $("#result").hide();
    }
    else {
        $("#result").show();
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/njq6mzpd/)

Comment: I forgot to add the JQuery already there. + It's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use JavaScript to perform this action as CSS does not support any way to identify empty input fields.

I have chosen to use jQuery for this example but it could easily be achieved using no external libraries.

```
$('.search').on('input', function() {
    $('#result').toggle( $(this).val() );
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7cfu5rs/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery

```
$( "#searchid" ).keypress(function() {
  var search = $( "#searchid" ).val()
if(search==''){
  $("#result").html();
}
});
```

Comment: I think it should be `$("#result").html("");`

Comment: I did that and it wasn't working:
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#searchid" ).keypress(function() {
        var search = $( "#searchid" ).val()
        if(search==''){
            $("#result").html();
        }
    });

</script>

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#searchid").keypress(function(){
    var len = $("#searchid").val().length;
     if (len <= 0)
     {
         //make result blank
        $("#result").hide();
     }
  });
});
```

**edit:**

use `$("#result").hide();`

**or**

```
$("#result").css("display","none");
```